# Classifying and evaluating Stack Overflow posts

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I was trying to evaluate and classify Stack Overflow posts using some objective metrics extracted from a Stack Overflow data dump as a research project. I need some expert advice about the applicability of those metrics. I used these metrics:

1. Acceptance rate (no of up votes/total votes)
2. Rejection rate (no of down votes/total votes)
3. Comment count
4. View count

Then I used a heuristic threshold for the rejection rate ([Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle)) to separate promoted and discouraged posts. For example, if 20% votes are downvotes, then it is quite likely to contain discouraging elements and if 95% are upvotes, then the post is more likely to be a good post. More details can be found in the technical report: *[Subjective Evaluation of Software Quality Using Crowdsource Knowledge: An Exploratory Study](http://www.cs.usask.ca/documents/techreports/2013/TR-2013-01.pdf)*

I am expecting some constructive suggestions on the approach.

Comment: One thing I'd look at is your use of "code" as an object.  "A discouraged code" or "A promoted code" is incorrect.  First off, on SO we promote or downvote answers and questions, not code.  Second, "code" is not really an object in this context even if it were appropriate; it would be "A promoted block of code".

Comment: well, lets consider the block of code then, but I am wondering what possible metrics I can consider more and whether these metrics are appropriate enough for evaluation or classification.

Comment: I guess my point is that you cannot evaluate the code itself: you evaluate the answer as a whole.  Good code could still be a poor answer (for example, insufficient or incorrect explanation), and bad code could be a good answer (sufficient explanation for the OP to understand the point).

Comment: Well, I am evaluating the SO posts right now not the code. So, are those metrics good enough?

Comment: @MasudRahman Good enough for what?

Comment: Yeah, can you share some more about your context and your goals? A lot of upvotes, for example, can tell  you that an answer is *probably* good, but I wouldn't bet my house on it. Because there's editing, downvotes don't *necessarily* mean a question is bad in its current form. Etc., etc. Btw, this blog run by a SO engineer may be of interest: http://kevinmontrose.com/

Comment: Actually, this is a research problem and my plan is to use the good or bad quality code fragment from StackOverflow for many other purposes like code quality evaluation of similar projects or recommending code snippets. As a first step, I am evaluating the posts

Comment: You _really_ have to take into account age or at least number of views. Some very old very simple questions and answers have very high score, where the same question asked today would be downvoted and closed, while its answer would gain just a few votes. You should also take into account tags. Different tags have very different viewing and voting patterns.

Comment: yup, I am concentrating on the questions and answers related to Java tags

Comment: You have to state a behavior model for posters and voters. Explicitly, from the first (psychological) principles. This much is absent from your paper. Votes, comments etc. are just indicators for the latent variables in the model. What's also missing is the posts and posters' heterogeneity.

Comment: +1 for interesting comment, any related articles you can refer?